# Transfer values from JSON to Google sheet using python

Tags: json, python-3.x, google-sheets, python-3.7, smtplib

So I have this code below which shows the number of times emails have been sent to a particular email address (from a list of emails saved in Google Sheet) and it countups the value in different sessions the code runs. The values are stored in a JSON file.

Is there a way I can push these values from JSON file to Google Sheet directly from Python. I want to do this without using [Pandas](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-read-and-write-data-to-google-spreadsheet-using-python-ebf54d51a72c) dataframe and IMPORTJSON function in Google sheet.

As a newbie to programming and Python, I have tried researching this but have come to a dead-end. Any help appreciated for this.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

# login & open sheet sheets
scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('my-jsonfile.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
sheet3 = client.open('Dashboard').worksheet('Sheet3')  # Open the spreadsheet
sheet1 = client.open('Dashboard').worksheet('Sheet1')  # Open the spreadsheet
sheet4 = client.open('Dashboard').worksheet('Sheet4')  # Open the spreadsheet

###Countup ###########

import smtplib
import ssl
from email.mime.text import MIMEText  # New line
from email.utils import formataddr  # New line

# User configuration
sender_email = 'email'
sender_name = 'username'
password = "password"

x = sheet3.row_values(4)
c = len(sheet1.col_values(8))
cell = ("")

from collections import Counter
import json

counter_file_path = "counter.json"
try:
    with open(counter_file_path, "r") as f:
        email_stats = json.load(f)
except FileNotFoundError as ex:
        email_stats = {}

successful_emails = []

for x in range (4, c):
    names = sheet3.cell(x + 1, 6).value
    emails = sheet3.cell(x + 1, 8).value
    if names == cell and emails == cell:
        print("no_data")
    else:
        receiver_names = list(names.split())
        receiver_emails = list(emails.split())


        # Email text
        email_body = '''
            This is a test email sent by Python. Isn't that cool?
        '''

        for receiver_email, receiver_name in zip(receiver_emails, receiver_names):
            print("Sending the email...")
            # Configurating user's info
            msg = MIMEText(email_body, 'plain')
            msg['To'] = formataddr((receiver_name, receiver_email))
            msg['From'] = formataddr((sender_name, sender_email))
            msg['Subject'] = 'Hello, my friend ' + receiver_name
            try:
                # Creating a SMTP session | use 587 with TLS, 465 SSL and 25
                server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
                server.ehlo()
                # Encrypts the email
                context = ssl.create_default_context()
                server.starttls(context=context)
                # We log in into our Google account
                server.login(sender_email, password)
                # Sending email from sender, to receiver with the email body
                server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, msg.as_string())
                print('Email sent!')
                successful_emails.append(receiver_email)
                if receiver_email in email_stats:
                    email_stats[receiver_email] += 1
                else:
                    email_stats[receiver_email] = 1
            except Exception as e:
                print(f'Oh no! Something bad happened!n {e}')
            finally:
                print('Closing the server...')
                server.quit()
                # counter = Counter(successful_emails)
                # print(counter)

print(email_stats) # output - all occurrences for each email
with open(counter_file_path, "w") as f:
     results = json.dump(email_stats, f)
```

The results of the JSON file are `{"receiver_emails_1": 6, "receiver_emails_2": 6}`

Comment: What is your expected output? How are you wanting them to be displayed in the sheet?

Comment: So I want the values to be displayed in a column corresponding to each email ID in the Google Sheet, where the list is saved.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.
Please reference to this documentation.
(Update a range of cells using the top left corner address). 
https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#example-usage

```
import json
import gspread
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials

# connect to your google sheet
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file('key.json', scopes=scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
wks = gc.open("your spreadsheet name").sheet1

# Let's say you have some json values
x =  '{ "receiver_email_1":6, "receiver_email_2":8, "receiver_email_3":10 }'
y = json.loads(x)

result = []
for key in y:
    result.append([key,y[key]])

wks.update('A1', result)
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response. I tried applying to my script above and I am getting a error `TypeError: update_cells() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given`

I just applied the following to the last part of the code to the code above, 

`to_sheet = []
for key in email_stats:
    to_sheet.append([key,email_stats[key]])

sheet4.update_cells(1,1, to_sheet)`

Anything I can do to get rid of the error?

Comment: I think you are using update_cells() method incorrectly. If you look at the documentation, https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Worksheet.update_cells , you should initialize a list of cells and then set their values before calling 'update_cells()'. So, what I suggest you is using `wks.update('A1', result)` . 'A1' is the specified left-hand cornor. You can use 'B3' 'C6'... as you like. the `result` should be a list of (list with 2 elements). 
`wks.update('A1', result)` will do finally.

Comment: Hi, I tried doing exactly the same but I am getting an error `wks.update('A1', results)
AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'update'`

Comment: If this is the case, your variable `'Worksheet'` is not a sheet object. My code is `wks = gc.open("your spreadsheet name").sheet1`. I first open the spreadsheet, then reference sheet1. For your case, just make sure you are referencing your sheet.